# Как провести LineCast не от центра объекта

Tags: unity3d

Я вызываю LineCast от дочернего объекта (с координатами отличными от родительского), с colider и Rigidbody но он работает точно так же если я буду проводить LineCast от родительского объекта.

**Фото где Родительский объект не видит колайдер (Дочерний видит):**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Фото где Родительский объект уже видит колайдер (Дочерний всё так же видит):**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*И только здесь он срабатывает, и то только потому что родительский объект его видит.*

Эффект работы точно такой же, что при вызове LineCast'a от дочернего или родительского объекта.

Как можно провести LineCast, чтобы он работал как было задумано?

**UPD:**
Проблема возникает и в случае если LineCast провести от родительского объекта. Я могу провести до любой точки луч, но начать от любой не могу (только от центра родительского объекта)

**Код к UPD:**

```
rend = plrRend.GetComponent<Renderer>();
Vector3 rightUpPlr = new(plrRend.transform.position.x - 2f, rend.bounds.max.y, rend.bounds.min.z); //попробовал со всех сторон



if (Physics.Linecast(rightUpPlr, closest.transform.position, out RaycastHit curhitInfo))
{
    lineDrawer.DrawLineInGameView(rightUpPlr, closest.transform.position, Color.blue, Color.red);
}
```

Comment: А в чем собственно вопрос?

Comment: @МихаилРебров, вопрос в том, как бы провести LineCast не только с центра объекта. Возможна эта проблема не так связанна с дочерними объектами, как не возможность проводить LineCast не из центра объекта, я пока всё ещё мучаю unity)

Comment: @NENE, а мы мучаемся с экстросенсорикой, плохо видя, как это делает задающий вопрос) Вечно все гадалки на больничных, когда нужны.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот почему тексты бесполезны и мы смотрим только на код.

> Я вызываю LineCast от дочернего объекта

Вот это ты называешь дочерним объектом? с colider?

```
new Vector3(plrRend.transform.position.x-2f, rend.bounds.max.y, rend.bounds.min.z);
```

В каком месте это дочерний объект? `bounds` это не `collider` и не `colider`. `bounds` это `bounds`, находящийся в компоненте `Renderer`, который никак с столкновениями не связан от слова "ВАЩЕ"!
Это координата, где `x`, `y` и `z` набор случайных и не связанных между собой значений.

```
public Transform Target;
[SerializeField] private Transform _chield;

private void Update () 
{
     if (Target != null) 
     {
         CastAndDraw(transfrom, Target);
         CastAndDraw(_chield, Target);
     }
}

private void CastAndDraw (Transform from, Transform target) 
{
    if (Physics.Linecast(from.position, target.position, out RaycastHit curhitInfo))
        lineDrawer.DrawLineInGameView(from.position, target.position, Color.blue, Color.red);
}
```

`bounds` вообще использовать не нужно. Это техническая штука, куб описывающий границы занимаемого пространства.

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Renderer))]
public class DrawBounce : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnDrawGizmos ()
    {
        Renderer renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        Gizmos.DrawWireCube(renderer.bounds.center, renderer.bounds.size);
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: "Вот это ты называешь дочерним объектом? с colider?" Нет, я даже подписал что это код к дополнению. Спасибо твой код помог, буду думать где это я так накосячил))

Comment: Всё работает и с Renderer'ом, похоже и в правду нужно было предоставить больше кода. Прошу прощение.

Comment: Дополнил про bounds.